# How do I update a watch complication when a value in a watch app is updated?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, watchkit, widgetkit

I created a custom/learner iOS app and watch app using Xcode 14 for iOS 16.2 and WatchOS 9.1. The apps have one real-world user. The apps use CoreData to store activities locally. The apps use WCSession transferUserInfo() to transfer a JSON representation of a new activity to the counterpart device, and then the counterpart saves the new activity to its CoreData db. This works well and the app views update dynamically.

Using Xcode, I added the target for the watch widget extension and slightly updated the boilerplate code as shown below. The complication works as a link to the watch app.

Next I'd like to update the complication when a new activity is added to the watch app (which would include activities transferred from the iOS app). Activities are added by the user every 3 to 8 hours, so I don't think a set timeline with future entry dates makes sense. The complication only needs the time of the most recent activity so that it can display the time elapsed since that activity.

Specifically, how do I send the most recent activity's activityTime from the watch app to the complication when that value is updated?

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import OSLog

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", category: "Provider")
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> mostRecentActivityEntry {
        mostRecentActivityEntry(date: Date(), activityTime: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (mostRecentActivityEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = mostRecentActivityEntry(date: Date(), activityTime: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var mostRecentActivityTime: Date?
        
        var entries: [mostRecentActivityEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = mostRecentActivityEntry(date: entryDate, activityTime: mostRecentActivityTime)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct mostRecentActivityEntry: TimelineEntry {
    var date: Date
    var activityTime: Date?
}

struct MostRecentEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Log")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
            if let time = entry.activityTime {  
                Text(time, style: .relative)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            } 
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ActivityLogWatchWidgetExtension: Widget {
    let kind: String = "ActivityLogWatchWidgetExtension"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(
            kind: kind,
            provider: Provider()) { entry in
            MostRecentEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Time Since Last Activity")
        .description("Displays the time since the last activity.")
    }
}

struct ActivityLogWatchWidgetExtension_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MostRecentEntryView(entry: mostRecentActivityEntry(date: Date(), activityTime: Date().addingTimeInterval(-1000)))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .accessoryRectangular))
        MostRecentEntryView(entry: mostRecentActivityEntry(date: Date(), activityTime: nil))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .accessoryRectangular))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## StackOverflow Response

After working on this for a couple more days, key pieces of information for me were that WidgetKit has replaced ClockKit and that the watch app and its complication can share simple data using UserDefaults.

I needed to add an "App Groups" capability for both the watch app and watch widget extension (complication). The group name that worked for me was "group.[MY PHONE APP BUNDLE IDENTIFIER]", though it's probably good to avoid names longer than 40 characters because they will be truncated when displayed, but not behind the scenes. That cost me some time.

When a new activity is created in my watch app either directly or when transferred from my phone app, I save the mostRecentActivityTime to UserDefaults and reload the complication's timeline via WidgetCenter:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: mostRecentActivityTime)
UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.[MY PHONE APP BUNDLE IDENTIFIER]")?.set(dateString, forKey: "mostRecentEmptyTime")
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

In the widget extension, I get the mostRecentEmptyTime value from UserDefaults and add one entry to the timeline. A reload policy of .never works when a complication only changes when the watch app sends a new value.

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [mostRecentActivityEntry] = []

    let entryDate = Date()
    let dateString = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.[MY PHONE APP BUNDLE IDENTIFIER]")?.string(forKey: "mostRecentActivityTime")
    if let dateString {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        if let mostRecentActivityTime = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            let entry = mostRecentActivityEntry(date: entryDate, activityTime: mostRecentActivityTime)
            entries.append(entry)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

The only remaining issues is that the phone app transfer of a new activity using transferUserInfo() to the watch app doesn't update the watch complication until the watch app is opened. I don't believe using sendMessage() would improve things, because the Apple docs state that "Calling [sendMessage] from your iOS app does not wake up the corresponding WatchKit extension."

Comment: You have to use transferCurrentComplicationData() instead of transferUserInfo().

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Can transferCurrentComplicationData() send the data from iOS to watchOS while in background?

Here is my situation. My app on iphone will run some tasks (in background), and when it's done, I want to send this data to watchOS. Then the next time watch complication refresh it can use the newly updated data. Up to this point I only use  transferUserInfo(), and new data never get sent to watchOS. Unless I have to open the app on watchOS, which is not ideal. Thanks.

Comment: @Boon The docs of `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo` (see header file): _Enqueues a user info dictionary containing the most current information for an enabled complication. If the app's complication is enabled the system will try to transfer this user info immediately. Once a current complication user info is received the system will launch the Watch App Extension in the background and allow it to update the complication content..._

Comment: @Boon Oh, I am sorry. Just noticed that your question was about transferCurrentComplicationData(). I will check later...

Comment: @Boon Once again, sorry. Already in my original comment I used `transferCurrentComplicationData`, which is a custom function in my code ☹️. It calls `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo`, and this function actually transfers complication data also in the background . Thus, the cited docu above does apply. Sorry for the confusion, my bad.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Thank you very much and no problem at all. But, can I use this for widget complication? not the legacy clockKit complication. How do you receive the userInfo - 'didReceiveUserInfo'? Sorry for more questions... but I have tried many things and nothing seems to work well.

Comment: Try the following: Use `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo` to send the complication data to the watch. It will be received in the background. But then, you have to transfer the data from the watch app to the widget app, which is in a different sandbox. To enable the widget app to read the data, you had to use an App Group that is shared between the watch app and the widget app. When the watch app received the complication data using `didReceiveUserInfo`, call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines`, and the `WidgetCenter` reads the new data from the App Group, and updates the complications.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but without success. :(  transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo is not as reliable as I would expect. It works every time if I open the app on watchOS. (app is active). But for most usage case, the app won't be opened at all as the app is intended to be widget complications. And what makes it worse, transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo will need to be run in background on iOS as well. I would hope one day Apple would make sending and refreshing widgets data more straightforward. Thanks you!

Comment: @Boon did you figure out how to make transferCurrentComplicationUserInfomwork? In a new WatchOS app that’s based on SwiftUI with an app delegate adapter, and the OS doesn’t seem to invoke the didReceiveUser info in the background, like, ever. I’m suspecting this may be a bug with the new single-project app approach in Xcode 14 because it used to work ok in a project with a separate WatchKit extension.

Comment: @Antonio Nope I still can’t figure it out. But in my testing the didReceiveInfo works but it is just unreliable. I mean I can’t tell when it will work or when it will not work. It’s a mystery. Lol.

Comment: @Boon, you said "transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo will need to be run in background on iOS as well." Why do you think so?

Comment: @kelin I meant in my case, 99% of the time it will be run while in the background because users won't be using my app. My app is a widget app. And it is very unreliable for it to run while app is in background. Hope it makes sense.